# MVC drop down list set selected

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to set the value selected in my drop down from the model value.
Can somebody help in this where I can set the model value to get selected.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<p>
  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
</p>
<p>
 @Html.DropDownList("categoryvalues", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Category, "Select")
</p>
}
```

Tried below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Type, new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Category,"Value","Text",modelItem => item.Type.ToString()))
```

I am getting error

Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Can you show us your model passing to the View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an enum, as mentioned in your comment, try my enum helper....

http://jnye.co/Posts/4/creating-a-dropdown-list-from-an-enum-in-mvc-and-c%23

This will allow you to do the following:

**In your controller:**

```
//If you don't have an enum value use the type
ViewBag.DropDownList = EnumHelper.SelectListFor<MyEnum>();

//If you do have an enum value use the value (the value will be marked as selected)    
ViewBag.DropDownList = EnumHelper.SelectListFor(MyEnum.MyEnumValue);
```

**In your View:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownList")
@* OR *@
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Property, ViewBag.DropDownList as SelectList, null)
```

Here is the helper:

```
public static class EnumHelper
{
    // Get the value of the description attribute if the   
    // enum has one, otherwise use the value.  
    public static string GetDescription<TEnum>(this TEnum value)
    {
        var fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        if (fi != null)
        {
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

            if (attributes.Length > 0)
            {
                return attributes[0].Description;
            }
        }

        return value.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build a select list for an enum
    /// </summary>
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>() where T : struct
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        return !t.IsEnum ? null
                         : new SelectList(BuildSelectListItems(t), "Value", "Text");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Build a select list for an enum with a particular value selected 
    /// </summary>
    public static SelectList SelectListFor<T>(T selected) where T : struct
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        return !t.IsEnum ? null
                         : new SelectList(BuildSelectListItems(t), "Text", "Value", selected.ToString());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BuildSelectListItems(Type t)
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(t)
                   .Cast<Enum>()
                   .Select(e => new SelectListItem { Value = e.ToString(), Text = e.GetDescription() });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is supply the value from your model and a `SelectList` object:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategorySelectList, "Select a category")
```

where `Category` is a property on your model and `CategorySelectList` is a `SelectList` object on your model.

I would recommend building your `SelectList` object in your model so you don't clutter your view with any casting or object building.

Comment: I tried this still value is not selected I tried below  `@Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.Type, (SelectList)ViewBag.Category, "Select" )` my case item.Type is an enum value from the model.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this inside my controller :

```
 ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(SelectAllList(),"ID", "NAME",selectedValue);
```

selectedValue is the id you want selected.